# SQL SELECT query not working with parameters, but works fine with concatenation

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, select, parameters

I'm trying to select the name of a customer based on the selected code from a `ComboBox`. When I run the following code, I get an error saying that there's no value for one or more required parameters.

```
sql = "SELECT [Customer_Name] FROM [Customers] WHERE [Customer_Code] = @code"
Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@code", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cmbCustomer.Text

Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
Dim ds As New DataSet

da.Fill(ds)

txtCustomer.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Customer_Name")
```

However, when I run the same query but without the parameter, it works fine.

```
sql = "SELECT [Customer_Name] FROM [Customers] WHERE [Customer_Code] = '" & cmbCustomer.Text & "'"
Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)

Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
Dim ds As New DataSet

da.Fill(ds)

txtCustomer.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Customer_Name")
```

Is there something really obvious that I've missed with the first way of doing it? If not, why is this way not working?

Comment: Should it be `cmd.Parameters.Add("@code", cmbCustomer.Text);`?

Comment: I believe you better use Parameter.AddWithValue instead

Comment: Where are you trying to run this query? directly, from a form, or report?

Comment: @SteveSmith No, none of my other queries have the semi-colon and they all work fine

Comment: @apomene No, `AddWithValue` is not the best way of doing it, that has to try to match the best datatype, which can cause issues

Comment: @ChanceFinley From a form, on the `ValueChanged` method of the `ComboBox`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of the `OleDbDataAdapter`

You're setting the `DataAdapter` to take the string of `sql`, and connection of `con`, which means the `cmd.Parameter` is not passed in with it.

So your code would be looking for `da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add`.

You either need

```
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Code", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cmbCustomer.Text
```

Or

```
Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
```

Comment: Wow, yes, how stupid. Thanks for the explanation too, I'll be more careful next time!